# How to create a counter with win percentage and leaderboard in rock, paper, scissors

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a rock, paper, scissors game as a beginner into JavaScript.

I am doing it on JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/hxapdh4t/2/

**My main  objectives is:
1. A measure of how many times a user has won in a row. If the user wins more than 5 games in a row, they get to add their name to the leaderboard.**

Some help on how to achieve this would be really helpful

```js
var score = 0
var ovens = 1
$("#circle").click(
function cook () {
 score=score +(ovens+1)
  $("#score").html(score)
}
)
$("#circle").click(
 function(){
  cook()
  }
)
  $("#buy").click(function() {
   if (score > 50) {
    score = score - 5
    ovens = ovens + 150
    }
    }
 )
    $("#score").html(score)
```

```html
<img src ="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1463/8084/files/10212_Protein_Cookie_LandingPage_Intro_Cookie.png?9894363475332233051" id = "circle" style="width:190px;height:180px;"/>
<p>
score: <span id = "score">0</span>
</p>
<button id = "buy">
Buy new oven
</button>
```

Comment: To store score permanently, for multiple users, you'll need a server. To store score for a single browser, you can use localStorage. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score -1):

You will need a way to store your scores if you want to make leaderboard, for example MySQL server. But to store score locally you I assume you would set variable that stores it or have it stored as cookie/localstorage.

Comment: Can you explain on how to use localstorage on this game. I read through some websites and I am not sure how to implement this into my rock paper scissors game.

Comment: Something like this to add to the local storage 

`localStorage.setItem('highscore', '1337');`

and to get highscore as JavaScript variable 

`var myHighscore = localStorage.getItem('highscore');`

Comment: Is it possible to do this?

A measure of how many times a user has won in a row. If the user wins more than 5 games in a row, they get to add their name to the leaderboard.